# React image upload not working through fetch

Tags: reactjs, api

```
    const submitData = (ev) => {
        ev.preventDefault();
        let formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("topicName", topicName);
        formData.append("topicMessage", topicMessage);
        formData.append("pictures", pictures);

        const requestOptions = {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
            Accept: "application/json, text/plain, */*",
        },
        body: formData,
        };

        const sessionId = localStorage.getItem("sessionId");
        let url = FormatUrl(`/api/v1/support/topic?sessionId=${sessionId}`);
        fetch(url, requestOptions)
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((res) => {
            ToastsStore.success(
            "Ваше обращение отправлено, среднее ожидание ответа 6 часов"
            );
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
        });
    };
```

Here i am sending data to upload file like this but no response getting back from Server.

Same things working in postman. Please refer to the screenshot.
Please take a look how can i fix it.

[image: .]

Comment: try removing  Accept: "application/json, text/plain, */*", or  formData.append("pictures", pictures.files[0]);

Answer (score 0):

I've done some researches here.
I found this nice website: https://muffinman.io/blog/uploading-files-using-fetch-multipart-form-data/ .
Apparently you should try to remove the content-type header.

Though if it doesn't work, please inspect the network and share the request made on chrome / firefox. (F12 -> Network and then try your request)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of appending data to the object like `formData.append("topicName", topicName)`, use something like `formData["topicName"] = topicName`

This might solve your issue. Let me know if that helped.